# How to Point multiple places in google maps

Tags: html, css, google-maps, iframe

Being a newbie in web development especially with google maps, I am exploring to mark three city points at a time on the world map of google. At this moment the Iframe of the maps only points to single location https://maps.google.com/maps?q=queensland&hl=en&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=42.360237,86.572266&hnear=Queensland,+Australia&t=m&z=5&iwloc=A

Its respective IFRAME is below, it only shows queensland location, is it possible to mark other locations, lets say Newyork, Paris, in the same IFRAME . THis iframe will be consumed in a website

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=queensland&amp;hl=en&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=42.360237,86.572266&amp;hnear=Queensland,+Australia&amp;t=m&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;z=5&amp;iwloc=A&amp;ll=-20.917574,142.702796&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=queensland&amp;hl=en&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=42.360237,86.572266&amp;hnear=Queensland,+Australia&amp;t=m&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;z=5&amp;iwloc=A&amp;ll=-20.917574,142.702796&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

Comment: are you looking for something like this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex

Comment: This is also really cool.IS How can i consume an iframe for this. All i am looking is for pointing multiple flags/bubbles in a single map.

Comment: this should get you started: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

Comment: Dont know the exact reason but running this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex in local host loads only the maps but not the flags

Comment: if you look at the javascript, on the function called setMarkers(), there is a line that sets the image of the marker (images/beachflag.png).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using "My custom map" option in Google Maps

- You can go to google maps, login in using gmail account
- Under location search on top left, click on "My custom maps"
- Then click on "Create", after that click on "Untitled map", give a "Title" and
  "Description"
- Search the locations you want to get a green marker, click on it and
  "add to map"
- click on "share" button in top right, change access to "Public on the
  web" and save

After that click on the folder button left of "Add layer" in the left panel and choose "Embed on my website", you will get an 'iframe' of the map including all the locations. Put it on your website n enjoy!!!

Note: if not shared to public, the embed code won't be available